# Redux Toolkit is not working with react.tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

index.js:1 ./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.legacy-esm.js 331:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (331:12)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |     return false;
  |   }

> if (cache?.has(value)) return false;
> |   const entries = getEntries != null ? getEntries(value) : Object.entries(value);
> |   const hasIgnoredPaths = ignoredPaths.length > 0;

Someone said to update "@types/react": "18.2.46" but this answer has bad reviews. Please help to solve the problem. Following is my package.json file, in case if there's any compatibility error of anything with redux toolkit

```
{
  "name": "in",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same.  Looks like it's because it can't parse the optional chaining ("?.") - googling around seems to lead to articles saying this is an issue with Webpack 4 - but I think latest SPFX is using Webpack 5.  Have you found any solution to this?  I'm trying to look into injecting additional Webpack config (babel?) but not getting anywhere useful yet.

Comment: If you dig deep into node_modules/@microsoft/gulp-core-build-webpack/node_modules/webpack/package.json it turns out that the webpack version in use is "version": "4.47.0" - which doesn't support optional chaining

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working here, by injecting babel-loader into the webpack config:

Install babel loader and plugins/requirements (note: version >=9 didn't work for me with current SPFX 1.18.2)

```
npm i babel-loader@8.3.0 --save-dev
npm i @babel/preset-env --save-dev
npm i @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining --save-dev
npm i core-js@3 --save
```

And then in your gulpfile.js:

```
build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
  additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration) => {
    generatedConfiguration.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.js$/,
      include: /@reduxjs/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ["@babel/preset-env", {"modules": false, "useBuiltIns": "usage", "corejs": 3}],
            ],
            plugins: [
              "@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining",
              "@babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator"
            ],
            cacheDirectory: true
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    // console.log({rules: generatedConfiguration.module.rules});

    return generatedConfiguration;
  }
});
```